# Using quick OSM plugin in QGIS to create a map of Tennessee

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, quickosm

I want to just make a map of Tennessee from the Quick OSM plugin in QGIS. How to achieve that?

Comment: Could you share what you have tried to far?

Comment: Easier to use QuickMapServices plugin, unless you really need to customise.

Comment: @GforGIS I have sort of figured it out. I went on the OSM plugin and selected a spot on the Tennessee map then I used the OSMinfo plugin to create an outline around Tennessee. Then I could make it a temporary layer and clip it that way.

Comment: @MigArr check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quick OSM to download all the data for Tennessee, however that would be a lot of data. You can just type the word Tennessee in the search area then click on "Run Query". You could type the name of a small town if you want as well. I would create a preset though and add "Query Keys" to avoid downloading what I do not need.

[image]

[image]

In this example for the sake of demoing, I chose the bicycle_road layer and clicked on "Run Query"

[image]

Here is my result:

[image]

You can use the extent of Tennessee layer if you have that to download the data as well. Just change the option from "In" to "Layer Extent"

[image]